# SQL combine CASE and AND

Tags: sql

How to combine an SQL `CASE` statement with multiple `AND`, such that I can check for multiple conditions i.e.
I want to randomly change `region` from `233` to `244` for `shopid = 455`:

```
select
    id,
    case region
       when 233 and shopid = 455 and FLOOR(RAND()*(3-1)+1) = 1 then 244
       when 233 and shopid = 455 and FLOOR(RAND()*(3-1)+1) = 2 then 233
       else region
    end
from 
    table1
```

I get this error:

> Operand '233' part of predicate '233 AND shopid = 455' should return type 'BOOLEAN' but returns type 'INT'.

FYI `FLOOR(RAND()*(3-1)+1)` will either yield 1 or 2

Comment: Case when REGION = 233.............

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the other form of `case`:

```
select
id,
case 
  when region = 233 and shopid = 455 and FLOOR(RAND()*(3-1)+1) = 1 then 244
  when region = 233 and shopid = 455 and FLOOR(RAND()*(3-1)+1) = 2 then 233
  else region
end
from table1
```